# How to extract the value of column 1 when column 2 changes?(python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas.DataFrame of the form.(It doesn't matter if you use numpy.)
I want to output a value of 'moID' whenever the value of column 'time' changes.
I'll show you a simple example below.
I will mark the row that should be output as '<<<'.

```
index 'moID' 'time'
0       1      0     <<< 
1       25     0
2       3      1     <<< 
3       45     1
4       12     1
5       2      2     <<< 
6       34     1     <<< 
7       4      1
8       12     1
9       2      3     <<< 
10      5      3
11      37     3
12      85     0     <<< 
13      2      0
14      45     1     <<< 
15      55     1
16      2      3     <<< 
17      23     3
18      42     0     <<< 
19      1      0
20      42     1     <<< 
21      2      2     <<< 
22      41     2
23      3      1     <<< 
24      52     1
25      2      1
26      24     3     <<< 
27      3      3
28      5      3
```

result is :

```
    index 'moID'
            1
            3
            2
            34
            2
            85
            45
            2
            42
            42
            2
            3
            24
```

help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to see if consecutive rows match and create a boolean Series (where it's False if the time is the same but True if it's different). Then use it as a mask to filter the desired items:

```
out = df.loc[df['time'].ne(df['time'].shift()), 'moID']
```

Output:

```
0      1
2      3
5      2
6     34
9      2
12    85
14    45
16     2
18    42
20    42
21     2
23     3
26    24
Name: moID, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *boolean indexing* the following way:

```
result = df.moID[df.time.diff() != 0]
```

`df.time.diff() != 0` generates a *Series* of *boolean* and it is used
to index *moID* column.

The result, for your source data, is:

```
0      1
2      3
5      2
6     34
9      2
12    85
14    45
16     2
18    42
20    42
21     2
23     3
26    24
Name: moID, dtype: int64
```

The left column is the index and the right one - actual values.